# MYSQLI Fetch Array

Tags: php, codeigniter

So far I have the code that gives me `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#166 (1) { ["id"]=> string(2) "92" }}` the following result but what do I have to do to enable me to use it via `mysqli_num_rows`?

**Code**:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT `id` FROM $table WHERE $table.id ='$product_id'");

        $result = $query->result();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **affected_rows**() like

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT `id` FROM $table WHERE $table.id ='$product_id'");
$result = $query->result();

$row_cnt = $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Comment: I am still getting ` mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given`

Comment: previously i have given ans with mysqli_num_rows,but now given with affecte_rows()

Answer (score 1):

when doing `SELECT` you must use `num_rows()`

when doing `UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE` use `affected_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

The row count can be found with:

```
echo $query->num_rows;
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)